# How to incorporate VLC into my VB Programming using VLCActiveXPlugin_V2

Tags: vb.net, vlc

I am trying to incorporate VLC into my VB program. I have included the COM tool VLCActiveXPlugin_V2. In the ‘openfiledialog1’ properties the ‘InitialDirectory’ is set to ‘E:\Movies\’,which is where my .mp4 movies are stored. When I run the program and press btnLoad the openfiledialog1 opens E:\Movies but it said ‘No items match your Search’! The code is adapted from a .net tutorial and works fine for him. I am ‘ASSUMING’ it was written with an older version of VB and/or .NET.

Anybody have any ideas?

This is just a test trying to get the playback to work, the end product will be that a user can create a DataGridView listing of the available movies, pick one of the movies and ‘hopefully’ the program will play that movie.

Code:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    btnLoad.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = " (*.mp4)  | .mp4 "
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    btnStart.Click
    AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.play()
End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    btnStop.Click
    AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.stop()
End Sub

Private Sub btnPause_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    btnPause.Click
    AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.togglePause()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: `"Movies (*.mp4)|*.mp4"`

Comment: Jimi, I tried your way also, but it didn't make any difference. In doing more investigating it was suggested to add "File:///" to the 'add' line, ie:        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("File:///: & OpenFileDialog1.FileName & "")

Comment: *No items match your Search*. This is what my comment is about. The filter you're using is wrong and that is the message you receive: it doesn't match any file because no files have a ` mp4` extension (with a space). The extension is `.mp4`. It also assumes that there are `.mp4` files in that directory, and that the directory is the one you're referring to, because I don't see where you're setting it.

Comment: It still doesn't see the file listing in the directory on the desktop, but if I type a letter into the filename line it will show a listing of the .mp4 files in the directory and allow me to load and run one. Just to see if there would be a difference, I created the same program on my laptop and it ran without a hitch, the only difference in the settings was the Initial Directory setting in the OpenFileDialog1 properties. Guess I'll have to dig deeper. Debug isn't helping me at all on this one.

Comment: Re-check your filter, maybe you have a space somewhere on either side of the `|`.

Comment: The omission of the '*' was an error in writing the original question. Both the desktop and Laptop versions have it in the coding. The directory is set in the 'OpenFileDialog1' properties. so is not needed in the code line.

Comment: Yup, gonna have to go through it character at a time.

Comment: Found the problem Jimi, it was the space in the filter line, but not in front, but behind the *.mp4. (| *.mp4 ") couldn't see the forrest thru the trees. Thanks for waking me up. Now I just need to put this together with the DataGridView.